# How to correctly implement logging from C# K8s container app to Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

I am trying to send log entries to Application Insights from a Azure K8s pod and am completely stumped.
The framework is net6.0

I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    // This code adds other services for your application.
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

in Startup.cs and

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
        app.Services.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(),
        TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .CreateLogger();
```

in Program.cs

I already have a working availability telemetry since that only needs a properly configured Telemetry instance which our code supplies.
I know how to work with hostbuilder and all but everything is just confusing, there seem to be 10 ways to go about it that all use very different approaches than what our code uses.

I just need a dead easy solution. It doesn't need to do any auto-logging, just send entries at points I want.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use plain Application Insights together with the [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes). Easy to follow [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes/#microsoft-application-insights-for-kubernetes) on their project website.